Issues with Query, Filter, Popup, and Attribute Table for Published Annotation Web Layer
I have published an annotation layer as a web layer to a Portal. While the layer publishes successfully and the annotations display correctly, I am unable to use key functionalities like Query, Filter, Popup, or see Attribute Table.
Is there a solution to enable these functionalities for an annotation web layer?
Based on Esri documentation, the version of ArcGIS Enterprise must match or be greater than the version of ArcGIS Pro used for publishing. I would like to know if upgrading my ArcGIS Enterprise version will resolve this issue, or if additional steps are required.
